# ASP.NET: where is aspnet_wp.exe in IIS6

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, iis-5

As title said, I cannot find **aspnet_wp.exe** in II6.

Where is it or replaced in IIS6?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For IIS6 it's called w3wp.exe - see [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20100128060804/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/vivek/archive/2006/10/18/94436.aspx) for more info

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for it for debugging purposes. There will be multiple processes per application pool and you should be careful to attach to the correct process for the application pool your web app is running in.